# wildfly - accessing the admin console

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm new to wildfly and am following the documentation on how to get everything set up. I've added a user by running the add-user.bat script, but the administration console page is still telling me I haven't - even though trying to re-add the same user results in the cmd line telling me that the user already exists.

[image]

The wildfly documentation, and other guides, make it out to be simple : I'm not sure what I could possibly have missed. I set up the user as a management user, didn't make them belong to any groups, didn't change the realm and answered no to the last question I don't understand.

I also restarted Wildfly and my PC.

Is there any file I should look in to see if the user is correctly set up?

I assume it's mgmt-users.properties - but the user doesn't exist in that file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, how do you start wildlfy? Check whether you run the script from the right folder. Have you set $JBOSS_HOME environment variable? if so check wheter it doesn't point to another wildfly location.

Comment: Hi Ivo - I start wildfly by typing `%WILDFLY_HOME%/bin/standalone.bat` from the command line. that results in `(WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 3379ms - Started 292 of 553 services (347 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)`. Browsing to localhost:8080 then takes me to the splash screen telling me that wildfly is running. RE environment variables - i assumed i could name it wildfly_home - is that not the case? sorry, i'm pretty new to this

Comment: and yes, at the moment there's only 1 wildfly location. i can't see any of the users in the .properties files (where various guides suggest they should be listed). but running add-users.bat tells me that the users *do* exist. it's definitely confusing me!

Comment: however - when i try to connect using `jboss-cli.bat` i get "The controller is not available at localhost:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053". Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990....... Connection refused: no further information

Comment: WildFly core or full WildFly? WildFly core doesn't come with admin console...

Comment: Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution - 11.0.0 Final http://wildfly.org/downloads/

Is the download I extracted. Regardless of the admin console, shouldn't I be able to use JBoss-cli to connect, stop and refresh the server? That just results in the 'Controller not available' error. Where as standalone.bat seems to start ok

Comment: I'm going to try on my desktop too, just to make sure it's not an issue with something on this laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone suffers from a similar problem I've discovered that this is a bug in WildFly 11.

I'm sure this is probably a pretty narrow problem, but swapping the directory for WildFly 10 fixes the issues of not being able to connect to the admin console and not being able to add users.

Comment: After you have added the user make sure you run wildfly standalone.bat from wildfly directory: `bin\standalone.bat`.

Answer (score 2):

Something else to be aware of if anyone runs into this. By default, the script assumes your deployment folder is named 'standalone'. If you have renamed this folder, the user will get created but the changes will not actually get applied to the server.

To fix this, simply open up the add-user script in a text editor and look for a commented out line that looks like

> #JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.config.user.dir=../standalone/configuration -Djboss.domain.config.user.dir=../domain/configuration"

Uncomment that line and change the path to match your directory name.

Comment: This was my case. Re-running the add-user.bat file after changing the path also works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/server.log** file for any error message and also see all the ports opened by wildfly in this log file.

You can use the following netstat command also to check all the ports opened by wildfly process ID:

**netstat -tnlpa | grep**

It might be possible that some other process is already using this port 9990.

-Param

Comment: I used netstat -an|find "9990" because I'm on windows. it found one instance, which I assume is WildFly, because I originally had to kick NvNetworkService off that port, and when WildFly starts it outputs: `11:48:03,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
11:48:03,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management`. The server log doesn't list anything of note other than a couple of security warnings. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mgmt-users.properties should be edited. If it is empty, why does it tell you user already exists? Can you check permissions of file?

Comment: worth following up for others i guess. it was actually comodo internet security which had a shadow drive for sandboxing. the cmd-line was reporting it was writing to mgmt-users.properties in %JBOSS_HOME%, but really it was a different file.